Error when i I'm trying to build appbundle in terminal with flutter the problem is signingConfig signingConfigs.release
signingConfigs.release gives me an error.
When i tried signingConfig signingConfigs.debug appbundle was built. jks file it' s ok and key properties too. I tried many suggestions but none worked for me. If anybody has or had the same problem and found what the issue was please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
}

When i try  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug it works perfectly with release it doesn't

Error: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle     A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable

kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message)

